# How do I troubleshoot a node not appearing in workbench?

Tags: 8, workbench

I have a bug report where a user is not able to see 'Draft' status nodes that they have just created in their workbench interface (at `/admin/workbench`). They are able to see other nodes in various approval phases.

I've backported the site to a local development environment and logged in as that user and I'm able to re-create the issue. Also, with my administrator user, I have the same issue -- the new node doesn't show up in my workbench queue either. However, it does show up in the content overview. The problem is that for most users, we only give them workbench queues to access content, and not the content overview.

I've looked at the various configurations for workbench, and at the fields on the new nodes, and I don't even have a starting point as to what to look at to troubleshoot this issue. My users are able create and publish content on a daily basis, so there's not a major misconfiguration in the site.

What makes a node appear in a workbench queue in Drupal 8? We have both the `workbench` and `workbench_access` modules enabled. I'm not sure how these interact with the core workbench features.

**Edit** I noticed in the [module page](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench) that "Workbench core is a series of Views", so I looked in the views on our site. We seem to be using the built-in-views, so I edited the "Workbench: Recent content (Content)" view, and removed the Filter Criteria "Content: Published status or admin user". I thought this would prevent my user from seeing the new node. However, after I removed that filter criteria, the draft node still did not appear in the preview of that view. So that doesn't seem to be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Absent the "right way to do it", what I've done is go ahead and given "Bypass Access Restriction" permissions to certain roles. That allows them to get their work done, but I would like to know what the correct thing here is.